# Swift 2 / iOS 9 - libz.dylib not found

Tags: swift, google-analytics, swift2, ios9, google-analytics-sdk

I'm using some external codes from google in my new Swift 2.0 project that required "libz.dylib" in earlier versions. After updating to the new Xcode / the new SDK.

Xcode is now unable to import the libz.dylib and throws some errors

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_deflate", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>     "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>     "*deflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByCompressingBytes:length:compressionLevel:mode:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>     "_inflate", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>     "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>     "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
>         +[GAICompressionUtil gai_dataByInflatingBytes:length:isRawData:] in libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When looking through the available packages in the "build phase" settings I can find "libz.tbd" which seems to be the replacement for the libz.dylib. When importing this lib the linker error stays the same but I get this additional warning:

> warning: skipping file '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd' (unexpected file type 'text' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)

What to do?

Comment: try Product Clear. If it doesnt help. delete Xcode caches and derived data

Comment: I concur with @LeoDabus to use "Product Clear". As a new project, adding this tbd (what does it stand for?) will compile fine.

Comment: I already cleaned and rebuilt the hole project - same issue!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found some kind of way around.

1. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
3. From /usr/lib you can add : libz.dylib and more...
4. Compile and have fun

Comment: This is outdated. It should be libz.tbd now.

Comment: @BK   Maybe it should, still does not work for me on Yosemite with Xcode 7.1.1 with .tbd - using the above solution does work in the simulator and on the device

Comment: It also seems like now you don't even need to have them in your Link Binary with Libraries list -- at least in my case Xcode finds them automatically. As in AZ0's answer below.

Answer (score 84):

libz.dylib is now found under libz.tbd
[quote from the Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9176#9176):

> For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new "text-based stub
>   libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub
>   libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its
>   download size.

Hopefully more documentation will be coming soon.

***edit***

To clearify it, i will cite Guitz answer with the updated Content

> 1. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
> 2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
> 3. From /user/lib you can add : **libz.tbd** and more...
> 4. Compile and have fun

Comment: This should be the first answer!

Comment: Is this safe to use on older iOS versions? on the link you provide they say "Delete all references to .tbd", so, should we use .tbd or not?

Answer (score 8):

Remove all dynamic libraries (dylib) from the linking with binaries phase. It will find these libraries on its own.

Comment: Thank you! It really works just like that. The problem for me with Xcode 7.2 that the simulator uses .tbd and iphone device / archive uses .dylib. So it complained that it cannot find missing libraries.

Comment: Simply removing the libraries was the right answer in my case. It seems like they had to be there in the old version of Xcode, but in the current version that I'm using (8.1) it works without them.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem in objective-c project.ios9.1,xcode7.1

1.Go to Target> Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > +

2.select libz.tbd and add it

It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also add the `lybz.dylib` from *"Other Linker Flags"* in the *Build Settings* by adding the argument `-lz`.

I had to do this because, using the method where you reference the library from /usr/lib, when I deployed my app to our testers the .dylib library could not resolve and caused the app to crash on launch.

Answer (score 1):

libz.dylib is the dynamic lib for Zlib, You can install Zlib from here http://zlib.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can add libz.1.dylib from location:/usr/lib/

1. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do CMD+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
3. From /user/lib you can add : libz.1.dylib

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Meanwhile you can use previous SDK. This is my answer for libsqlite3:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981161/627794

*Edit: (link content added)*

Open terminal, type (change to your desired library, e.g. libz)

```
locate libsqlite3.dylib
```

You'll find several files like these:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
```

Go to your project's setting -> Build Phases -> Link with Binaries. Add BOTH files by clicking `+`, then `Add Other`. Hit `Cmd-Shift-G`, and copy-paste the file path. Click `Open`.

If you install sqlite3 using macports, remove `/opt/local/lib` from Library Search Path in Build Settings.