# How to link to libz and libsqlite in xcode 7 beta?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I got linkage error like:

```
   +[WeChatApiUtil DecodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      +[MTAWXOHelper GZip:Out:] in libWeChatSDK.a(MTAWXOHelper.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      +[MTAWXOHelper GZip:Out:] in libWeChatSDK.a(MTAWXOHelper.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
```

But I've already added those library to my target. But currently all those library have different extension .tbd.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in this other [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815806/swift-2-ios-9-libz-dylib-not-found%20%22here%22.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a known issue in XCode 7 while linking tbd files. Here is the link to the apple developer forum answer on how to link tbd files in XCode 7 - https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/8609#8609

[Snippet from the link is available below]

> This is a known issue in the Xcode 7 beta.
>
> To work around this issue for now, please:
>
> - Delete all references to .tbd files from either your linked libraries phase, or from the copied bundle resources phase (where they sometimes will be added).
> - Add the library you want to link manually to the "Other Linker Flags" build settings, by adding the argument: -l for each library you want to link (for example, add "-lsqlite3" (without quotes)).
>
> For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its download size.

Comment: "...  and help to significantly reduce its download size, at the expense of it not actually working" :)

Answer (score 4):

I have two project using zlib, one which finds it to link, one which doesn't. I set them both up by using the "+" in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". I finally figured out how to fix the non-working one:

1. Remove all links to zlib that you added in previous attempts
2. Open Finder, head to `/usr/lib`, and drag the `libz.dylib` alias into your project's Frameworks folder
3. Compile. This worked on 2015/08/23 for me.