# How to convert .tbd file to .dylib?

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode

Is there anyway to convert `tbd` library into `dylib`? The original dylib file has lost since Xcode converted dylib into tbd from 7.0. Is there anyway to recover them?

Comment: Do you need just to recreate the dylib?
If so, this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815806/swift-2-ios-9-libz-dylib-not-found

Comment: I too would like to know if I could convert a .tbd file into a .dylib stub.  That way, I could cross-compile for Mac OS X using the `lld` linker from LLVM, which does not currently support `.tbd` files.